# application.properties always assigned to default value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

For context, here I'm using intellij and Spring boot 2.0.0.

I have this configuration in my spring boot project's application.properties

```
prop=${PROP_VARIABLE:defaultValue}
```

Then I assign someValue to PROP_VARIABLE in intellij's gradle task run configuration.
When I check the env via actuator the prop is always assigned to defaultValue, but if I assign it like this

```
prop=someValue
```

It's correctly assigned to someValue

Where's the problem here and what can I do to inject the env properly?

Comment: @Devilluminati Sorry, I don't understand. What exactly should I add to the vm args (vm options in run configuration?)

Comment: add it to the vm args like -DPROP_VARIABLE

Comment: @Devilluminati I can't really do that since there's a huge number of properties variable in my project